# Adding List Data queires in Anywhere Administration application in Maximo

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am using the Anywhere Administration application in Maximo.
What I am trying to do is to add several WorkList queries to the WorkExecution app.  (I do have worklight.properties with si.adminmode=true, and I have run Anywhere-Admin-Loader allApps with ant).

I have additional queries in there that have been added using SQL and work fine on the mobile device.

But when I try to add one using the app there are no values to select in the Select Value list for QueryBase ID.

There are additional saved queries in the WOTRACK saved queries

But even if I try and type one of the values in I get an error.

Has anyone else come across this and have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug on Maximo's with an Oracle database, fixed in the 7.5.2.1 fixpack that made this Select Value list empty.  Could that be the issue that you're hitting?

Comment: I cant see anything in 7521 that would affect the way that Maximo would run.

Comment: There should be a class file fix in the 7521 anywhere admin pmp to fix this issue.

Comment: The problem that I was hitting was I had tried to upgrade from 7521preview to 7521.  The 7521 fixpack does indeed fix this issue.